# Rails 3.2 - Can't connect to local MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion

When I run the app, I will get this error message:

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
```

If I try to run

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

The result is:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
```

I am pretty sure I was working with Rails 3.2 and MySQL, but now it doesn't. I am running on Mac OS Lion, could you help me please what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Go to your settings and clique on the MYSQL button. Then press start MYSQL SERVER. Done! You got this message because your server has not been start.

Answer (score 2):

Type `ps aux | grep mysqld` in the terminal and see if anything shows up besides the grep command. If not, you're mysql server isn't running. Otherwise try typing `mysqld start` in the terminal and see if you can't get your sql server to boot up.

Edit: Sorry, on OSX the command to start it should be `mysql.server start`

Comment: In the statement of `ps aux | grep mysqld` is just the `ps` command. I think the right command for Mac OS is `sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start`, but when I run it, I see in terminal `Starting MySQL database server`. But when I run then the Rails app, I get again `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)`...

Comment: `ps aux | grep mysqld` is a way to see if your server is running, not a command to start running it. On OSX the proper command to start a mysql server is `mysql.server start`.

Comment: If I run `mysql.server start`, the output is `-bash: mysql.server: command not found`. Does it mean that MySQL is not installed?

Comment: Your setup could be very different than mine, but I've worked on several macs and that seemed to be the command on all of them. After you started MySQL your way, what does ps aux | grep mysql give?

Comment: Just this, nothing more: `adam           2379   0.0  0.0  2432768    584 s000  R+    9:19AM   0:00.00 grep mysql`. Does it mean that Lion OSX installation broke the MySQL?